# Loop video with MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play videos that I receive through server.

I want to loop video forever.

I already tried `MPMoviePlayerController repeatMode` attribute (I did `repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One`).

Then I tried with the

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("videoHasFinishedPlaying:"), name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)`
```

And the function that get's called when notification is fired.

But I have the problem that none of these work on iOS 7 and iOS 8. They work great in the simulator, but on real device they don't.

Any suggestions how can I fix the problem?

Comment: I ended up with my own solution.

I changed `MPMoviePlayerController` with `AVPlayer` and it works great both on iOS 7 and iOS 8.

I added this comment yust in case if anyone else get stuck with the same problem as I did.